# How to edit object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to edit JavaScript object.

I have an JavaScript object like this

```
data_without_id = [
                   0: {id: 1, name: "Mary", age: null}
                   1: {id: 2, name: "Bob", age: 33}
                   2: {id: 1, name: "Kelly", age: 40}
                  ]
```

I want to convert this object into this

```
data_without_id = [
                   0: {id: 1, name: "Kelly", age: 40}
                   1: {id: 2, name: "Bob", age: 33}
                  ]
```

What I need to do is:

1. Group by `id`
2. Get latest value.

I tried using `Array.prototype.reduce()`, but I can't get the result I need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the function `reduce` would be as follow:

The function `reduce` for grouping and the function `Object.values` for extracting the values.

```js
let data_without_id = [  {    id: 1,    name: "Mary",    age: null  },  {    id: 2,    name: "Bob",    age: 33  },  {    id: 1,    name: "Kelly",    age: 40  }],
    result = Object.values(data_without_id.reduce((a, {id, name, age}) => {
      a[id] = {id, name, age};
      return a;
    }, Object.create(null)));

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for super fast response! It works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.reduce` by making the accumulator an object that has keys of the `id`. This way you can overwrite any previously seen objects which had the same `id`, and then use `Object.values` to get your array of objects:

```js
const data_without_id = [{id: 1, name: "Mary", age: null}, {id: 2, name: "Bob", age: 33}, {id: 1, name: "Kelly", age: 40}],

res = Object.values(data_without_id.reduce((acc, obj) => 
  (acc[obj.id] = obj, acc)
, {}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just simply use a `for/of` loop to create a copy of the data where the last object with a particular id will always be the object returned in the output data. This avoids the "grouping" part of the code but still returns the correct data.

```js
const data_without_id = [
  { id: 1, name: "Mary", age: null },
  { id: 2, name: "Bob", age: 33 },
  { id: 1, name: "Kelly", age: 40 }
];

function lastId(arr) {
  const out = [];
  for (let obj of arr) {

    // If you don't create a copy of each object the returned
    // data will simply be contain _references_ to the original
    // data. Changes in the original data will be reflected
    // in the returned data
    out[obj.id - 1] = { ...obj };
  }
  return out;
}

const lastIds = lastId(data_without_id);
console.log(lastIds);
```